# Right-justify single item in a centered, column-aligned flex container

Tags: css, flexbox

I've searched and found discussion of right-justifying an item on a row-aligned flex, but not a column-aligned one.

I have several lines of text. Each line is centered horizontally, and the container is positioned vertically. However, one line is in a footer and I want to right-justify it.

I've tried every combination I can think of to right-align the footer (various values for `align-self`, changing the footer to use `inline-block`, changing `justify-content` in the footer, etc.), and everything results in it being *left*-justified.

The CSS in the two `section` elements are set; I can't change them. I can do whatever I want in the `footer` (within reason).

How do I get the text in the footer right-justified, i.e. on the right side of the window, i.e. what `text-align: right` would do if this wasn't in a flex container?

```
<section>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Morbi at interdum odio</p>
  <p>Maecenas mi ex</p>
  <footer>
    <p>Nunc ultricies</p>
  </footer>
</section>
```

```
section{
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: calc(70vh - 3em);
}

section > *{
  margin: 0;
}

footer {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`align-self:flex-end`

```css
section{
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: calc(70vh - 3em);
}

section > *{
  margin: 0;
}

footer {
  margin-top: 1em;
  align-self:flex-end;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Morbi at interdum odio</p>
  <p>Maecenas mi ex</p>
  <footer>
    <p>Nunc ultricies</p>
  </footer>
</section>
```

OR `text-align` if you make the footer `width:100%`

```css
section{
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: calc(70vh - 3em);
}

section > *{
  margin: 0;
}

footer {
  margin-top: 1em;
  text-align:right;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Morbi at interdum odio</p>
  <p>Maecenas mi ex</p>
  <footer>
    <p>Nunc ultricies</p>
  </footer>
</section>
```

Comment: Good grief. I tried end, and self-end, and flex-end on justify, and somehow missed flex-end on align-self, or maybe did it while I changed something else that caused it not to work. Thanks!